# Trying as assign a SQL string to the record source property of Access report

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form pictured below.  Three sort buttons, 1 preview report button.

[image: sort and preview buttons]

When the sort buttons are clicked, a publicly declared variable called strsql is updated.

I have this code at top of Form

```
Option Compare Database
Public strsql As String
Option Explicit
```

strsql is updated and used to populate the list area.

One of the buttons click events

```
Private Sub cmdReturnDate_Click()
   strsql = strSQL1 & strSQL2 & Me!cboDistricts.Value & weekEndSort
   Me!teachersList.RowSource = strsql
   Me!teachersList.Requery
 End Sub
```

I am trying to use strsql as the recordsource for the report being called on the Preview Report button.

I have this line of code in the event open function for the report and can see the correct sql in the variable strsql

```
Private Sub btnPreviewReport_Click() 
  MsgBox (strsql)

  Rem assign the sql string to the reports data property.
  DoCmd.OpenReport "reportname", acViewPreview

 End Sub
```

I either need to pass the sql to the report or reference the variable in the reports recordSource property.

attempt to reference in report open event

```
 Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)

   Me.RecordSource strsql

 End Sub
```

The report is currently not showing data, not recognizing the variable - no output.

**Question is:  How can I access/assign strsql to the reports recordsource property?**

Answer (score 0):

`Me.RecordSource strsql` should be `Me.RecordSource = strsql`

But do you know there is a `WhereCondition` option when you open a report ?
You can also use `OpenArgs` to pass a parameter to the report/form when you open it.

```
docmd.OpenReport reportname:="SomeReport", _  
                 whereCondition:="Category = 33", _
                 openArgs:="Furniture"
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the report hidden, set the recordsource then close the report and save:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "SomeReport", acViewDesign, , , acHidden
Reports!SomeReport.RecordSource = strSQL
DoCmd.Close acReport, "SomeReport", acSaveYes
```